# How to open first mail of user in user Lotus Notes mail file (nsf file) via Serverside Javascript

Tags: xpages

When a user logons after then I would like to create a link to reach the first mail of user in XPages via ServerSide Javascript. When the user clicks the links which opens the first mail.

is there any way to make this work?

Regards
Cumhur Ata

UPDATE:

```
var mailDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(), mailFile);
var mailView:NotesView = mailDb.getView("($Inbox)");
var unreadEntries:NotesViewEntryCollection  = mailView.getAllUnreadEntries();
if (unreadEntries.getCount()>0)
{
    var veUnread:NotesViewEntry = unreadEntries.getFirstEntry();
    var dt:NotesDateTime = veUnread.getDocument().getItemValueDateTimeArray("DeliveredDate").elementAt(0)

    for (var i=0; i<unreadEntries.getCount() && i<3; i++)
    {
        //I can get field values. Find the DeliveredDate below..
        var dt:NotesDateTime = veUnread.getDocument().getItemValueDateTimeArray("DeliveredDate").elementAt(0)
        //I think Where I need to create DocLink is here but not succeded yet :(
        var veUnread:NotesViewEntry = unreadEntries.getNextEntry(veUnread);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean open in NotesClient, in WebMail or as Document Datasource?

Comment: in web mail like opening a document in web browser.

Comment: It is indeed possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please find what i have tried so far. I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it easier. Simply construct the URL from `@MailDbName`, and `/($Inbox)/$first` which will open the first document in the inbox. See the [URL Command documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_DOMINO_URL_COMMANDS_4332.html) for details

Comment: It will however not take into account if the mail is read or not